boundingBoxCollection length is 0
    const { selectedButton } = this.state;

    var boundingBoxCollection = [];
    console.log(boundingBoxCollection.length);

    var boundingBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('.cropper-face');
    console.log("I am ice"+boundingBoxes.length);

    if(boundingBoxes.length > 0){
      boundingBoxes.forEach(elem => {
        if(!boundingBoxCollection.includes(elem)){
          boundingBoxCollection.push(elem);
        }
      });
    }

my boundingBoxCollection is not updated
fix this, I want my array to be updated

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

const { selectedButton } = this.state;

// Ensure boundingBoxCollection is initialized properly
var boundingBoxCollection = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.cropper-face'));

console.log("Initial length: " + boundingBoxCollection.length);

// Loop through the selected elements and push them into boundingBoxCollection
var boundingBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('.cropper-face');
console.log("I am ice" + boundingBoxes.length);

if (boundingBoxes.length > 0) {
  boundingBoxes.forEach(elem => {
    if (!boundingBoxCollection.includes(elem)) {
      boundingBoxCollection.push(elem);
    }
  });
}

